# Understanding deployment and hooks

Tags: gatsby, contentful, vercel

I'm trying to understand the process by which a Gatsby project would update itself based on a Contenful data change. Let's say that I push a small change to a piece of content (let's say I switched a boolean from false to true) would the Gatsby hook get triggered on every change (since the webhook calls out to Vercel/Gatsby Cloud or whatever is being used for building)?

In that build event would the whole site get built and redeployed or just the content that has changed? I'm curious because if there's a complete rebuild of the whole site wouldn't that incur n number of API calls to Contenful? Seeing as their free service is maximum 2 million API requests/month, that could get consumed quickly.

Can someone point me to documentation on a flow that is efficient? Ideally something that only updates the pages or content pieces directly affected by the content change? I believe Gatsby Cloud has this granular publish ability?

Comment: Publishing a content change from Contentful would trigger the Contentful hook and would re-build your gatsby site. If you are using Gatsby cloud, potentially this triggers an incremental build.

Comment: Yup, ok I got that part at least but does that incremental build query Contentful only for the portions that changed? I'm trying to figure out the impact on Contenful's API calls to see if I can get content hosted within their 2m cap.

Comment: You did not provide enough details about your setup in order to answer your question. What it comes down to: How did you setup your site so a rebuild is triggered? A better question would be: How can I setup my site so a rebuild to is triggered when x happens

Comment: Are you specifically asking how many Contentful API calls are made each time `gatsby build` is run when using `gatsby-source-contentful`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was maybe a lot more too this question than I originally realised what was involved. Basically the framework needs to support Incremental Builds. Next.js and Gatsby both support it. I believe with Gatsby you need to use their Cloud product and pay the fee/use their deployment system. The magic is a paid solution (from what I gathered).

Ended up going with Next.js because it seems built into their tooling and it played well with other distribution mechanics I want to use. Ended up choosing Storyblok instead of Contentful. I dislike Contenful's weird 2M licensing model. The first price point also scared my client away.